# XML - XSLT to HTML check box are no displaying

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I am trying to generate HTML through C# code. Where I am passing xml and xslt file path locations. It is generating HTML but check boxes are not checked /Unchecked depending up on the value of xml node" NoFee". If NoFee=1 then that check box should be checked and if NoFess=0 then check box should be unchecked. It is just creating checkbox but not updating if we change NoFee Attribute to 0 or 1.
Also it is not reading loc_name node and not displaying value of loc_nam in to generated HTML>

I have xml like this

```
<root>
  <TopSectionelements>
    <TopSection>
      <key>01</key>

      <loc_nam>ALUMNI                                   </loc_nam>

      <NoFee>1</NoFee>
    </TopSection>

  </TopSectionelements>
</root>
```

XSLT is like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
<html> 
<head>
<style>
   div.container{
   width:100%;
   border:1px solid gray; 
   }
   table{
   display:table;
   <!-- border-collapse:collapse; -->
   border-spacing:1px;
   border-color:gray;

   }


</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">

  <table border="1">
<tr>
    <td colspan="2">Location of Occurrence <br/> <xsl:value-of select="loc_nam"/></td>


    </tr>

<tr>

     <td>
     <input type='checkbox' value='x'>
     <xsl:if test="root/Topsectionelements/TopSection/NoFee = 1">
     <xsl:attribute name="NoFeeChecked">NoFee</xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:value-of select="'checked'"/> 
     <!-- </xsl:attribute> -->

       <!-- <xsl:attribute name="checked">NoFee</xsl:attribute> -->

      </xsl:if> 
      </input>
      </td>
</tr>
</table>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:styleshee>
```

Answer (score 0):

A few issues...

- Your XLST ends with `</xsl:styleshee>` instead of `</xsl:stylesheet>`
- `Topsectionelements` should be `TopSectionelements` in your `<xsl:if>`
- The `input` HTML you were generating will not give you the desired result
- `loc_nam` needs to be prefixed with the full path

XML

```
<root>
  <TopSectionelements>
    <TopSection>
      <key>01</key>
      <loc_nam>ALUMNI                                   </loc_nam>
      <NoFee>1</NoFee>
    </TopSection>
  </TopSectionelements>
</root>
```

XLST (modified)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
   <xsl:template match="/">
      <html>
         <head>
            <style>
               div.container{
   width:100%;
   border:1px solid gray; 
   }
   table{
   display:table;
               <!-- border-collapse:collapse; -->
               border-spacing:1px;
   border-color:gray;

   }
            </style>
         </head>
         <body>
            <div class="container">
               <table border="1">
                  <tr>
                     <td colspan="2">
                        Location of Occurrence
                        <br />
                        <xsl:value-of select="root/TopSectionelements/TopSection/loc_nam" />
                     </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td>
                        <input type="checkbox" value="x">
                           <xsl:if test="root/TopSectionelements/TopSection/NoFee = 1">
                              <xsl:attribute name="NoFeeChecked">NoFee</xsl:attribute>
                              <xsl:attribute name="checked">checked</xsl:attribute>
                              <xsl:value-of select="'NoFee'" />
                           </xsl:if>
                        </input>
                     </td>
                  </tr>
               </table>
            </div>
         </body>
      </html>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Generated HTML

```
<html>
   <head>
      <style>
   div.container{
   width:100%;
   border:1px solid gray; 
   }
   table{
   display:table;

   border-spacing:1px;
   border-color:gray;

   }


</style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="container">
         <table border="1">
            <tr>
               <td colspan="2">Location of Occurrence <br/>ALUMNI                                   </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>
                  <input type="checkbox"
                         value="x"
                         NoFeeChecked="NoFee"
                         checked="checked">NoFee</input>
               </td>
            </tr>
         </table>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for detailed explanation. It worked.

Comment: It is working partially. When the value in XML node is '0' . It unchecked the check box but does not display the text along with check box. Just a small empty square box is displaying without ant name.